# XILINX A7: can I connect MMCM to MGTREFCLK1N_216?

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem with my MGTREFCLK1N/P_216 pins on my A7 xc200t board.

- I "should" connect it to a MMCM.
- I worry that it is not possible due to the physical placement of the bels and so on.
- Maybe it is not intended to be connected to a MMCM  but to the dedicated IBUFDS_GTE2.

Maybe someone can give me some information..

---

[image: package browser]

```
report_property [get_package_pins E13]
Property                Type    Read-only  Value
BANK                    string  true       216
BUFIO_2_REGION          string  true       TL
CLASS                   string  true       package_pin
DIFF_PAIR_PIN           string  true       F13
IS_BONDED               bool    true       1
IS_CLK_CAPABLE          bool    true       0
IS_DIFFERENTIAL         bool    true       1
IS_GENERAL_PURPOSE      bool    true       0
IS_GLOBAL_CLK           bool    true       0
IS_LOW_CAP              bool    true       0
IS_MASTER               bool    true       0
IS_VREF                 bool    true       0
IS_VRN                  bool    true       0
IS_VRP                  bool    true       0
MAX_DELAY               int     true       63514
MIN_DELAY               int     true       62882
NAME                    string  true       E13
PIN_FUNC                enum    true       MGTREFCLK1N_216
PIN_FUNC_COUNT          int     true       1
PKGPIN_BYTEGROUP_INDEX  int     true       0
PKGPIN_NIBBLE_INDEX     int     true       0
```

It says not clk capable.

```
Property                Type    Read-only  Value
IS_CLK_CAPABLE          bool    true       0
```

- So is there common way to connect **those** to Package Pins to a MMCM in Vivado?

- Or is it like:

#### IBUFDS_GTE2

These two clock Pins are hard wired to the The buffer IBUFDS_GTE2

[image: device browser]

##### Using Output of MUX for logic?

- Look please at the schematics.
- @ lower edge is a MUX (O and ODIV2)
- Can I connect the MUX Output to MMCM?

###### Timing?

- I heard MMCM should be connected close to the pins?
- Would this be then the case if I connect output of MUX to MMCM?

[image: schematics]

Comment: yes, connect `O` from `IBUFDS_GTE2` to `MMCM`. That's why they provide the pin. The long way would be the `TXOUTCLKFABRIC` output.

Comment: ok thank you :)  so this would be the closest for an MMCM right? (attention TXOUTCLKFABRIC is for "testing", I think you mean TXOUTCLK ).

Comment: I also have another question but maybe I need to open a new Question. I need a 50 MHz signal for those same transceivers (dclk). But it sais clearly in the xaui core description, that this signal should not be the incoming ref-signal. So i guess wherever I would put in a MMCM to the schematic above, to abbreviate  50 MHz, it wouldn't work right?

Comment: Don't care about testing :). It works. Does it want a so-called free-running clock? The clock from `IBUFDS_GTE2` is free running (it can't be disabled or interrupted).

Comment: PG053: dclk : "Clock used as the DRP clock, and also as a stable reference clock for the detection of the feedback and reference clock signals to the QPLL. The input reference clock to the QPLL or any output clock generated from  the QPLL ( for example TXOUTCLK) must not be used to drive this clock. For Ultrascale (...)"                               I wonder about "The input reference clock to the QPLL "  which would be the output IBUFDS_GTE2 of.